# How to dismiss all Google Photos Assistant cards using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-photos

I have too many Google Photos assistant's cards accumulated [image: Google Photos Assistant page]

How would I dismiss all those cards at once using JavaScript?

Comment: thanks @adiga for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript it's possible to do like this:

```
 var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("VfPpkd-Bz112c-LgbsSe material-icons-extended   VxYl6");

 for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
      if(buttons[i].getAttribute('aria-label') == 'Dismiss')
           buttons[i].click();
```

Update re HOW TO APPLY THIS CODE:

1. Open Developer Tools (CMD+Option+I, or Menu->More Tools->Developer Tools)
2. Select Console tab
3. Paste the above code

Comment: I dont know how to apply this code, could you please walk me through?

Comment: @CeyhunÖzsoylu, I've added instructions:
Update re HOW TO APPLY THIS CODE:

 1. Open Developer Tools (CMD+Option+I, or Menu->More Tools->Developer Tools)
 2. Select Console tab
 3. Paste the above code